# How to indent arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I indent arrays in PHP?

Say we have the following array

```
[Array] (
   [red] => 10
   [green] => 20
   [blue] => 30
)
```

How can I indent it in one level, so that I have this at the end

```
[Array] (
    Colors => [Array] (
       [red] => 10
       [green] => 20
       [blue] => 30
   )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you want your first array to become embeded in another one ?

If so, what about :

```
$newArray = array(
    'Colors' => $yourOldArray
);
```

Of course, `$yourOldArray` is the variable that contains your old array ;-)

Or you can replace the `$yourOldArray` part by the content of that old array itself.

Of, if the new array already exists, and you just want to add a sub-item to it :

```
$newArray['Colors'] = $yourOldArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array('Colors' => $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array['Colors'] = $origArray;
```